# Infra red remote control very short range

Tags: infrared, remote-control

I bought a house that has a few LG split air cons.

Whenever I want to use them I need to get like 2 meter close to them for the remotes to work which feels too short and annoying. These units are 10 years old and I already changed the batteries for all remote to try if it would solve the issue.

So my question is what could have happened over these 10 years to reduce the range of the remote controls? Is there anything I can do to improve it?

I thought maybe the plastic in front of the IR sensor got opaque? Any change the remotes or the receiver start to loose power over time?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest, best-case scenario for you: There's dust on the receiver lens that's blocking some of the light from reaching the receiver.

Another possibility: The plastic on either the transmitter or receiver lens has yellowed over time. Most plastics will do this, especially if exposed to UV(?) light.

Another possibility: The LED in the transmitter has degraded over time. There are a number of mechanisms by which LEDs lose efficiency over time as you suspected.

Comment: Another possibility is that someone changed out their nearby area incandescent lamp lighting for LED lamps (or fluorescent) and this is impacting the range in unplanned ways?

Comment: @jonk, good thought. OP, does the range improve if you turn the room lights off?